# How to set EBS root volume to persist for an EC2 instance within Elastic Beanstalk using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, terraform

I have written Terraform to manage my AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment and application, using the default docker solution stack for my region.

The EC2 instance created by autoscaling has the standard/default EBS root volume which is set to "true" value for the setting "DeleteOnTermination" -- meaning that when the instance is replaced or destroyed, the volume (and hence all the data) is also destroyed.

I would like to change this to false and persist the volume.

For some reason, I cannot find valid Terraform documentation for how to change this setting so that the root volume persists. The closest thing I can find is for the autoscaling launchconfiguration, a "root_block_device" mapping can be supplied to update it. Unfortunately, it is unclear from the documentation how exactly to use this. If I create a launchconfiguration resource, how do I use that within my beanstalk definition. I think I'm on the right track here but need some guidance.

Do I create the autoscaling resource and then reference it within my beanstalk definition? Or do I add a particular setting to my beanstalk definition with this mapping inside? Thanks for any help or example you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can done at EB level through [Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-resources.html).

Specifically, you have to modify settings of `AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration` that EB is using to launch your instances from.

Here is an example of such a config file:

**`.ebextensions/40_ebs_delete_on_termination.config`**

```
Resources:

  AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration:
    Type: AWS::AutoScaling::LaunchConfiguration
    Properties:
      BlockDeviceMappings:
        - DeviceName: /dev/xvda
          Ebs:
            DeleteOnTermination: false
```

Then to verify the setting, you can use AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 describe-volumes --volume-ids <id-of-your-eb-instance-volume>
```

or simply terminate the environment and check the Volumes in EC2 console.

Comment: Thank you. I am looking for a terraform-based way to specify it, if possible. But if that doesn't exist I will have to use some other mechanism like ebextensions.

Comment: @ScottShipp I'm not aware of doing this other way. The EB is constructing the CLoudFormation template for your environment. EB will look at your `.ebextentions` and modify the template accordingly. Terraform is not involved in construction of the template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ebs_block_device block within the aws_instance resource. This will by default delete the ebs volume when the instance is terminated.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html#block-devices

You have to use the above instead of the aws_volume_attachment resource.

> delete_on_termination - (Optional) Whether the volume should be
> destroyed on instance termination (Default: true).

Comment: I'm unclear how to connect the aws_instance resource to the aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment resource though? Right now I don't directly define anything having to do with autoscaling, the launchconfiguration, or the EC2 instance. I am passing some of the settings in the aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration to my resource and that's it.